# How to play audio with click method?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
     <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <title>Tytuł strony...</title>
 </head>
 <body>
        <div id="lista_mp3">
            <p>mp3/the_patients_heart_is_beating_very_fast.mp3</p>
            <p>mp3/get_across.mp3</p>
        </div>
        <audio id="player" controls autoplay src="mp3/the_patients_heart_is_beating_very_fast.mp3"></audio>
        <script>
            var lista_mp3 = document.getElementById("lista_mp3");
            var audio = document.getElementById("player");
            var paragrafy = lista_mp3.querySelectorAll("p");
            lista_mp3.addEventListener("click",function(e){
                audio.src=e.target.innerHTML;
                audio.playbackRate = 0.5;
                audio.play();
            },true);
            setTimeout(function(){paragrafy[0].click();console.log("klik "+paragrafy[0].innerHTML);},4000);
            setTimeout(function(){paragrafy[1].click();console.log("klik "+paragrafy[1].innerHTML);},8000);

        </script>
 </body>
```

Hello.

When I click "manually" in these two paragraphs, everything works. The mp3 file is replaced and the music plays;).
Unfortunately, when I use the click () method, the audio is not run. setTimeout starts the function, replaces the mp3 address but
the sound does not start. Interestingly, when I call any of the paragraphs  before calling setTimeout, click() method runs audio. What is going on? Somebody knows? Sorry for my English I hope you understand what I wrote.

Thank you very much.

Comment: because your using click event on list_mp3, but the click you put on the paragraph elements, turn them into buttons maybe

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can play audio/video without user interaction. It's there to prevent websites from annoying users.

As your setTimeout functions are outside the event listener, it is executed without any user interaction and hence it can't play the audio.
The click() method inside the setTimeout triggers a programmatic click, not an actual user's click so the click event listener will not play the audio, but it changes the src of audio element because that action does not require user interaction so a programmatic click can do that too.